# pdfx flutter package scroll wheel on web

Tags: flutter, mousewheel

The Pdfx Flutter package exhibits an unusual behavior when I use the scroll wheel on the web. I want to achieve a normal behavior, similar to when scrolling through a PDF file in a PDF viewer app.

Does anyone know how to fix this?